# How can I create multiple instances of an Angular Component?

Tags: angular, angular-components

I started learning Angular and now I am using it to create a chat interface.

The main parts will be a box displaying the messages from the user and the assistant in form of text bubbles, a box where the user can type the text that will be send to the chat and a button to send the contents of the box to the chat.

I created a Component for the user text bubble. How can I make it so that, when an input is submitted, a new instance of the UserTextBubble is created and appended to the chat dialog on the screen?

I know I can create an array and iterate through it to show a list on the screen, but if possible I don't want to keep all the inputs of the conversation in memory. I would like to just be able to insert it on the screen and just leave it there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ViewContainerRef` to dynamically add components.

To achieve this you can just add `ng-template` to you component `html` file with template reference.

```
<ng-template #chatContainer></ng-template>
```

Then in your `*.component.ts` you add `UserTextBubbleComponent` to the `ng-template` by using `ViewContainerRef`

To get `ViewContainerRef` from the template you can use the `#chatContainer` you defined in previous step to access it by using `@ViewChild()`.

```
@ViewChild('chatContainer', {read: ViewContainerRef}) vc: ViewContainerRef;
```

You will also need `ComponentFactoryResolver` so add it to `constructor()`

```
constructor(private factory: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}
```

To add component to the `#chatContainer` you can use this method

```
  addComponent(text) {
    const factory = this.factory.resolveComponentFactory(UserTextBubbleComponent);
    const componentRef = this.vc.createComponent(factory);
    (componentRef.instance).textToDisplay = text;
  }
```

What this method do is that it creates `ComponentFactoryResolver` for `UserTextBubbleComponent` which will allow you to create it by `createComponent`.

The last line is there instead of some `@Input()` inside of the `UserTextBubbleComponent`.

To be able to use it like this you also need to define the `textToDisplay` inside of the component.

So add `textToDisplay` inside of the `UserTextBubbleComponent` it will be the value of the chat bubble.

```
public textToDisplay: string;
```

You will probably also need to add the UserTextBubbleComponent to `entryComponents` array. Inside of `AppModule` add this under `imports`

```
 @NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, ...],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, UserTextBubbleComponent, ...],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [UserTextBubbleComponent, ...]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I have also made an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f8bz27)

Comment: UserTextBubbleComponent has to be added into entryComponents array?

Comment: Yes I have just updated the answer with it and with StackBlitz example

Answer (score 2):

You can treat your component like any other html element and use NgFor to loop over it providing whatever necessary data.

fake.component.html

```
<div>
  <your-component-selector-name *ngFor="let array of yourArry"></your-component-selector-name>
</div>
```

some good info on component interaction from the docs https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction